# Question about 'strong' assumptions and proving 'strong' result.

Tags: logic, proof-writing, terminology

When someone says "we can prove a stronger result", it means the new statement is more general and better than the previous.

However, when we add conditions to an argument, add more assumptions, we say "we need stronger conditions". But if we have stronger conditions then that means the result is not very strong since we have many assumptions.

Why do we use these terms? It seems to me stronger conditions = weaker result. So, weaker conditions = stronger result.

Certainly if we use as little assumptions as possible then the result would be strong, since it will hold more generally. If we use a ton of assumptions, that is stronger conditions, then the result would be too niche to be strong.

For example, why is 'strong induction' called strong induction? We are using more assumptions than 'weak' induction, hence stronger assumptions, but because we used so many assumptions, doesn't that make the result weaker?

Comment: Strong and weak induction are equivalent, so that might not be the best example.

Comment: Well, in strong induction, we use more assumptions than weak induction. It seems to me since we are using more assumptions, it would be weaker because we are assuming more.

Comment: To me, your explanations answer your own question...

Comment: There's lots of these dichotomies in the language of math. They are resolved by context. Nothing's perfect.

Comment: @angryavian I'm still confused as to why we say for example, strong induction.

Comment: Maybe someone should reiterate what Token said, because strong induction and normal induction are equivalent. Anything that can be proved with one can be proved with the other, so "strong" is a bit mis-used here.

Comment: It seems to me that the difference between strong induction and ordinary induction is in the process of the proof itself, not in the assumptions nor in the results.

Comment: @DavidK: That's exactly the point of my answer. Specifically, it's in the process of a proof **using** [strong] induction.

Comment: @user21820 Yes, I see what you mean. Good answer.

Answer (score 2):

$\implies$ is contravariant in its first argument (and covariant in its second) which is to say if
$$ R \implies P \qquad\text{ and }\qquad Q \implies S$$
then
$$ (P \implies Q) \implies (R \implies S)$$

The key here is the flipped $R \implies P$. Similar such contravariance leads to much other terminology like this. We simply say $H$ is "stronger" than $K$ when $H \implies K$ which will have this contraviant component if $H$ is a conditional statement (i.e. implication) as virtually all theorems of math are.  Of course, "stronger than", i.e. implication, is only a preorder, so $H$ is stronger than $K$ doesn't preclude $K$ is stronger than $H$, as is the case in your example where "weak" induction implies strong induction.

Comment: Your very reasoning implies directly that "weak induction" is stronger than "strong induction", which is indeed how we actually think of them, despite their names.

Answer (score 2):

As you noted, weak induction trivially implies strong induction, and ordinarily we would therefore say that weak induction is at least as strong as strong induction. However in this special case the naming is probably due to the fact that many times using strong induction yields a shorter proof than weak induction (shorter by the length of the proof of strong induction from weak induction). So in this sense strong induction seems stronger, but completely not for the usual reason.